# Skip apt faster if already installed using ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm using ansible to deploy to a server.
The apt stage (it is Ubuntu) takes a long time to run even if the correct version is already installed (I'm guessing it just runs and sees that nothing needs to be installed)

Example command:

```
- name: set up apt packages
  action: apt pkg=nginx=1.4.6-1ubuntu3.3 state=present update_cache=yes
```

(I have quite a few of those, so it takes quite some time)

Is there a way ansible can "figure out" pkg is already installed and run/skip this command faster?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you set `update_cache=yes` Ansible will run `apt-get update` at every run of the play.

[Ansible documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/apt_module.html)

> Run the equivalent of apt-get update before the operation. Can be run as part of the package installation or as a separate step.

By removing `update_cache=yes` the task should run a lot faster, because Ansible won't need to wait for `apt` to update its repositories.

Another option would be to register some file or path create by the package using the `stat` module. Something like this:

```
- stat: path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
  register: st

- name: set up apt packages
  action: apt pkg=nginx=1.4.6-1ubuntu3.3 state=present update_cache=yes
  when: not st.stat.exists
```

See [Ansible documentation for more examples](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/stat_module.html). But I would recommend just to remove the `update_cache=yes` parameter.